# How can I run my c++ code on terminal directly using geany

Tags: geany

I am new user of geany. When I run to view my current file Its open my terminal but It does not show my program output. I have type g++ filename.cpp then ./a.out. Its too boring. How can I set it so that when I run my code Its open my terminal and directly show my output?

Comment: If the build commands are correctly configured, it should just be a matter of hitting F9 to compile & link then F5 to run, Does that not work for you?

Comment: I think I did something wrong with build commands. So Its happend.Now how can I fix it?

Comment: I reset all the commands but It did not fix